# Error inflating class error when eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, navigation

I have moved eclipse project to Android studio. and used some of the eclipse jar files in Gradle. 
for navigation it is using [Blur Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/charbgr/BlurNavigationDrawer) and app built on it. problem is in new android studio project im getting error starting from following line.

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.charbgr.BlurNavigationDrawer.v7.BlurDrawerLayout`

since im new to android i dont understand what is the reason behind it. 
i have spent more than 3 days on this. really looking for help now.

Activity Class : -

```
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_main_activity);

            Fragment fragment = new CalendarMainActivity();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();

            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

            // Set up the drawer.
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                    (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
            restoreActionBar();

    }
```

Layout :-

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<com.charbgr.BlurNavigationDrawer.v7.BlurDrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:blurRadius="19"
    app:closeDescription="@string/navigation_drawer_close"
    app:downScaleFactor="0.0"
    app:drawerUpImageId="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:openDescription="@string/navigation_drawer_open"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragmentMainActivity">
```

Gradle File :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile files('libs/main.jar') // This contains the Blur Navigation
    compile files('libs/library.jar')
    compile files('libs/date4j.jar')
}
```

Comment: you might have incorrectly connected your JAR to the project. Pls show the `build.gradle` of your application module

Comment: @VladMatvienko i have updated the question with build.gradle

Comment: ok, all looks ok in it. You can try to connect it not through JAR, but through maven dependancy as it is described here: https://jitpack.io/#charbgr/BlurNavigationDrawer/18aa52fe63

Comment: also you'd better post a full stacktrace of the error

Comment: @VladMatvienko i tried maven method you showed here. its giving another error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Foreground is not initialised - invoke at least once with parameterised init/get`